# Retrieve rows with date before specified date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Original Question:**

Let's say I have a table - `Table 1` - that looks like this:

[image: 1]

How would I automatically populate the table - `Table 2` - below?

[image: 2]

The second table should only show the values from table 1 if they were available on 30 June. For example, `A` should only show a value of 10,000 and not 5,000.

---

**Updated question(to make it clearer to understand):**

[image: edited table]

Basically, how can I put formulas in cells `C16` to `C27` so that they will be filled up as in the picture above? Cells `C16` to `C27` must be able to retrieve the latest values for A,B,C,D available in the first table as at the dates in cells `E16` to `E27`.

**For example:** Cell C25 should return 15,000 because that's the latest available value at 30 September. It shouldn't return 20,000 because that value was only available after 30 September.

Thanks so much to everyone for all your help!

Comment: Suppose a name has multiple entries before the target date.  Is each supposed to be a separate entry in the second table (just a filter), or are all of the qualifying values supposed to be aggregated?  Is table 2 pre-populated with everything except the value results?

Comment: Hi fixer1234, I'm not sure how to reply your question (its really technical) but  I've amended my question. Hopefully it clarifies my situation! Thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: See if I'm understanding the problem correctly.  The second table looks like a quarterly report of activity that happened only during the last quarter, so anything covered in the previous quarter's report is not included again.  It looks like there can be multiple entries in table 1 for a given name within a quarter.  And it looks like you are not adding any multiple entries together to get a total; rather you are reporting just the most recent entry as of the end of the quarter. (cont'd)

Comment: Table 2 always contains one label and the quarter end date for each name, whether or not there is a value to report.  I'm guessing the actual names are not A, B, C, D, and there might not be a total of just four.  So where they come from and how they get into table 2 is not an issue and not part of the question.  For purposes of the question, table 2 already has the name entries and quarter end date filled in; the question is just how to fill in the value column.  And table 1 is in chronological "transaction" order regardless of name.  Did I get it right?

Comment: Hi fixer1234 you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

There are some simpler ways to do this in Excel.  However, I use LO Calc, and a few easy formulas that work in Excel don't work in Calc.  I had to use a method I could verify.  So here's a solution that also works in Calc.

This solution uses a helper column (what you see in column F in the screenshot), which you can hide if you don't want to see it.

[image: Screenshot]

My output for September 2016 doesn't match yours.  It took a few minutes to realize that's because you didn't include the September C and D data in your example.  My result is correct for the data.

#### Formulas

Lets start with the helper column.  Table 2 is based on names within calendar quarters.  The helper column gives you that.  The formula in F2:

```
=CEILING(MONTH(E2)/3)&A2
```

The first part calculates which quarter the date is in.  The name is concatenated to that using `&`.

That brings us to the meat of the problem.  The formula in C16 is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$12,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((F$2:F$12=F16)*ROW(F$2:F$12)))-1),"")
```

#### How it works

I'll explain the formula from the inside, working out.

- `SUMPRODUCT(MAX((F$2:F$12=F16)*ROW(F$2:F$12)))`

  The SUMPRODUCT identifies the row containing the last entry in the helper column that matches the name and quarter.
- `INDEX(C$2:C$12,last_matching_row-1)`

  INDEX picks that value from your data in column C using the row of that last value.  However, the location is specified relative to the range it's looking in, not the actual row on the workshhet, so the `-1` adjusts for that.
- `=IFERROR(formula,"")`

  The workhorse part of the formula calculates your result when you have data.  If there's no data, it returns an error.  So the formula is wrapped in IFERROR, which produces an empty cell if there's no data.

Comment: Wow that's amazing! Can't thank you enough for your help! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired results with the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B6,C1:C6, "<="&TEXT(K1,"dd-mm-yyy"), A1:A6,A1)
```

Column `B` is the values column from your Table A.

Column `C` is the Date column from your Table A.

"<="&TEXT(K1,"dd-mm-yyy") is <=30-Jun-2016 (There's probably a better way to do this).

Column A is the Name column from your table A.

the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) takes more than 1 criteria - so we are summing the values in column `B`, where the dates in column `C` are less than or equal to the date in cell `K1`, AND where the Names in column `A` match the name in `A1`.

I'm sorry for the poor layout of my answer, I am new to this - I hope this helps.

EDIT: Based on the updated information added to the question, my answer does not work. My answer sums the values but the question only calls for the most recent value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I appreciate it very much. Yes, I'm only looking for the most recent value. But all the same, thank you so much for your advice!